# Using DBI to connect to Oracle Database in Perl getting ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate in Windows

Tags: windows, oracle, perl, dbi

In windows machine, When trying to connect to Oracle Database via Perl (`strawberry-perl-5.32.0.1`) getting below error.

Error:

```
failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc.
```

Environment variables `ORACLE_HOME` & `PATH` are correctly pointing to oracle insta client 12.2 version.

Code shown below:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=hostname;service_name=servicename;port=xxx','username','password');
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved. ORACLE_HOME needs to be set at system level environment variable rather than account level environment variable